# Nested SELECT statement with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with this SQL statement and why it's not producing any results. If I take out the LEFT JOIN is works, so what's wrong with it?

```
SELECT  b.id, r.avg_rating
FROM    items AS b
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT avg(rating) as avg_rating
    FROM ratings 
    GROUP BY item_id
) AS r 
  ON b.id = r.item_id
WHERE b.creator = " . $user_id . " 
AND b.active = 1
AND b.deleted = 0
ORDER BY b.order ASC, b.added DESC
```

Would appreciate the help greatly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add the `item_id`  column in your subquery (*I guarantee that it will work*) so the `ON` clause can find `r.item_id`

```
SELECT item_id, avg(rating) as avg_rating
FROM ratings 
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, thank you SQL master John! I'll accept your answer in 12 minutes when it lets me!